# Git problem - checking my users/personal folder

Tags: git, github

I've got a little problem with git.
Today I started larning git, but something go wrong and now in visual studio see statement:
"The git repository at 'c: \ Users \ Personal' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled."
In github desktop I can see few hundred changes mostly in /appdata. I don't know how to stop this.
I tried to remove repository which was opened in this folder but nothing is working.

Comment: sounds to me like you created a repository at c:\users\personal and haven't actually deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you ran `git init` in your home directory. So now there's a folder at `C:\Users\Personal\.git`. If you didn't intend this then you can just delete that directory.

It's normal to create a folder for each project. If you're using visual studio the normal thing is to have a `C:\Users\You\Source\Repos` folder where all your projects will live. So if you have a project in `C:\Users\You\Source\Repos\YourProject` you can `cd` into that directory an run `git init` to create a git repository for that project.